# Highlighting the matching pair of a character changes the foreground color of Cursor

Tags: gvim, highlight

I'm using Vim 8.2 on Fedora 32. I have the following lines in `~/.vimrc` for highlighting the `Cursor`, `lCursor`, `CursorLine`, and `MatchParen` highlight groups:

```
highlight Cursor guibg=Green guifg=Black
highlight lCursor guibg=Green guifg=Black
highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE guibg=Gray7
highlight MatchParen guibg=fg guifg=bg
```

I also enabled RGB colors for vim with the below lines:

```
let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
set termguicolors
```

In gvim, when the matching pair of a charachter included in `'matchpairs'` is higlighted (as specified by the above highlight command for the `MatchParen` highlight group), the character under the cursor is highligted exactly as specified by the above highlight command for the `Cursor` highlight group (i.e. green bg and black fg). However, in vim, the foreground color of `Cursor` becomes the same as the background color of `MatchParen`.

Also, to disable any defaults unknown to me, I tried setting `cterm`, `ctermbg`, and `ctermfg` to `NONE` for all highlight commands, and disabling highlighting the current line, but nothing I did fixed the issue. I checked `:hi` for the set colors, and nothing surprising there. It seems strange to me that the highlighting is fine in gvim but not in vim.

UPDATE: The issue exists in xterm, but not in Gnome terminal.

Comment: Are you using termguicolors or no? If not, I wouldn't expect `gui..` highlighting to affect `cterm` highlighting—is it possible this is a case of "not specifying the attribute means use the default (whatever it is)"? Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks. Yes, I have `set termguicolors` (along with `let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"` and `let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"`) in `~/.vimrc`. I checked `:hi` for the set colors, and nothing surprising there. Also, to disable any defaults unknown to me, I explicitly set `cterm`, `ctermbg`, and `ctermfg` to `NONE` for all highlight commands as I said in the Question. Don't really know what's causing this, can it be a bug in `matchparen.vim` plugin?